# What does colon in job name means when using Gitlab CI pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

Using the following CI pipeline running on GitLab:

```
stages:
  - build
  - website

default:
  retry: 1
  timeout: 15 minutes

build:website:
  stage: build
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...

website:dev:
  stage: website
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

What does the first colon in job name in **build:website:** and in **website:dev:** exactly mean?

Is it like we pass the second part after the stage name as a variable to the stage?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Naming of jobs does not really change the behavior of the pipeline in this case. It's just the job name.

However, if you use the same prefix before the `:` for multiple jobs, it will cause [jobs to be grouped](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#group-jobs-in-a-pipeline) in the UI. It still doesn't affect the material function of the pipeline, but it will change how they show up in the UI:

[image]

It's a purely cosmetic feature.

Jobs can also be grouped using `/` as the separator or a space.

Comment: This only applies to where numbers are involved like `job 1:3`, `job 1/3` or `job 1 3`.